# Controllability to a linear manifold

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I received the following task as homework.

Given a linear controllable system $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu,\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ derive a criterion of the system being controllable to a manifold $Dx=b$, where $D$ is an $r\times n$ matrix of full rank and $Dx=b$ has at least one solution.

Controllable to a manifold means that for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exist time T and bounded control $u: [0, T]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that under that control $Dx(T)=b$.

I believe I have solved the task. However, the fact that my answer is independent of $b$ bothers me. I would like to get a second opinion.

My attempt:

Define $R=[B,AB,\ldots, A^{n-1}B]$. It can be shown that the span of columns of $R$ (denoted Im $R$) is exactly the space of states reachable from 0. It is also easy to see that for any $y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for some solution of the above system with zero control $x(0)=x_0, x(t)=y$. Basically, to show that any state $x_0$ may be controlled to a solution of $Dx=b$ we need to show that for any $y\in\mathbb{R^n}$ $$y+\text{Im} R\ \cap\ \{x|\ Dx=b\}\neq\emptyset.$$

Let $z$ be any solution of $Dx=b$. Then $\{x|\ Dx=b\}=z+\text{Ker}\ D$. Since $y$ is arbitrary, we have to show that $$y+\text{Im} R\ \cap\ \text{Ker}\ D\neq\emptyset.$$

Equivalently, we need to show that $\dim (\text{Im} R\ + \text{Ker}\ D)=n.$

$$\dim (\text{Im} R\ + \text{Ker}\ D)=\dim (\text{Im} R) + \dim(\text{Ker}\ D)-dim(\text{Im} R\ \cap\ \text{Ker}\ D)=\\ =\text{rank}\ R+n-\text{rank}\ D - \text{rank}\ R + \text{rank}\ DR = n-\text{rank}\ D+\text{rank}\ DR.$$

So, a linear controllable system is controllable to a manifold iff $\text{rank}\ D=\text{rank}\ DR$.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is impossible to drive the system to $D\,x(T)=b$ for all $D\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$ and $D$ full rank. Since for $r>n$ the equality might not have any solution. For example when $D = [I\quad I]$ and $b^\top=[v_1^\top\quad v_2^\top]$ with $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $v_1\neq v_2$

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Sure. Of course, it is assumed that a solution exists.

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier to just state that $x(T)=x_T$ for some $x_T\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Or do you mainly want to consider the case when $r<n$ such that there are infinitely many solutions for $x$ that satisfy $D\,x=b$ (and call that set of solutions the linear manifold)? So basically you want $D\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$ with $r\leq n$ and the rank of $D$ equal to $r$ (full rank).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, everything boils down to the case when $r\leqslant n$.

Comment: I think you don't need to introduce $y$ and $\operatorname{Ker}D$. By your definition, it is sufficient that at least one solution to $Dx=b$ is in the reachable subspace. This means the criterion is if there exists $z$ such that $DRz=b$, i.e. $b \in \operatorname{Im}DR$.

Comment: @obareey I don't think this is true since for the special case b=0 your suggestion implies any system is controllable to any manifold $Dx=0$.

Comment: @Serg So, $z$ needs to be nonzero. In the case $b=0$ this means $\operatorname{Im}R \cap \operatorname{Ker} D \neq \{0\}$

Comment: This discussion got me thinking. Since $0 \in \operatorname{Im}R$, it looks like $0$ is always reachable from any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is obviously wrong. So I think "$x_f$ is reachable iff $x_f \in \operatorname{Im}R$" condition is true only if $x_0=0$, i.e. reachability from zero definition.